Samba server in Solr Docker image, on localhost
Why
Accessing the data inside Solr is cumbersome. Need to ssh into /var/solr directory, and then use command-line operations. So instead, if I can just expose the data directory to a Samba share, and access with a GUI, that is more user-friendly.
Environment details
local

Windows host running Docker Desktop
Base Solr 9 Docker image

/var/solr is a local volume mount


Samba server is installed onto the base image

smb.conf file is copied from local as well



Cloud

Azure Container Instance of custom image
Base Solr 9 Docker image

/var/solr would be needing to be configured in the Azure env



At the moment, I am trying to get it to work on my local machine.
Configuration files
solr-develop.Dockerfile
FROM solr:9.6.0 as solr_dev
LABEL name="Solr DEVELOP"

# Switch to root to install packages
USER root

# Install Samba
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y samba && \
    apt install -y samba-common-bin && \
    apt install net-tools && \
    apt clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Switch back to the Solr user
USER solr

# Copy the Samba configuration file
COPY data/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf

# Expose Samba ports
EXPOSE 139 445

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh", "solr", "start", "-c", "-f"]

solr-develop.docker-compose.yaml
name: 'solr_develop'
version: '0.1'
services:
  solr:
    container_name: solr_develop
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: solr-develop.Dockerfile
    ports:
      ################### Solr ###################
      - "8983:8983"
      ############################################
      ############### Samba server ###############
      - "139:139"
      # 445 already in use by local system
      - "446:445"
      ############################################
    volumes:
      - ./data/solr:/var/solr
    # command:
    #   - solr-precreate

smb.conf
[global]
   loglevel = 5
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = Samba Server
   security = user
   map to guest = Bad User
   dns proxy = no

[solr]
   path = /var/solr
   browsable = yes
   writable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = no

Expected result
With the Samba service active, I expected the share to appear on my local Windows Network discovery somehow.
I do not know the following:

Where/how should I look to accessing this? File explorer networks
Any additional setting I need to turn on my localhost?

'resolve *.docker.internal DNS names from both the host and your containers' is enabled
The ports appear to be in use on localhost when the container is up.


Something in the configuration files needs to be modified?
The approach itself is wrong? Maybe should think of just also using an available Samba server image instead of installing


Exactly what problem are you trying to solve? Any reason why you couldn't mount a local directory instead as Solr's data directory and have direct access to the files in your local environment?

The main problem is that I cannot access my samba file share from outside the container, for example on my host Windows machine.
I am trying to match my local development environment as close as possible to the staging environment. For now I have discovered Azure File Shares, which apparently come with SMB access.
So I've changed my approach on it at the moment.
